# Store class instances in a python List

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a shopping cart Class. One of the methods takes an item as an argument and appends it to a list. Another function calculates the total cost of the items in the list. I have a `getCostOfItem` method in the item class. It seems to be I cannot get the methods of the item instances in the List. I am completely new to **Python** with some **C++** background.

```
from item import item

class Cart:
 def __init__(self,customerName,CartID, totalOrderAmount=0,currentSize =0):
        self.CART = []
        self.customerName = customerName
        self.CartID = CartID
        self.totalOrderAmount = totalOrderAmount
        self.currentSize = currentSize

 def addItemToCart(self,item):
        self.CART.append(item)   

 def TotalCost(self):
        for i in self.CART:
            self.totalOrderAmount += i.getCostOfItem() # problem`
```

Comment: Whats the class spec for items in the cart?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle class item:
    def __init__(self,name,quantity,cost,ItemType):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.cost = cost
        self.ItemType = ItemType

Comment: And the respective getter methods

Comment: You would be better adding to the totalOrderAmount as you add each item, and call to TotalCost should just return the value of totalOrderAmount

Comment: you should add the relevant code for item and an example of what you add and expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store class instances in lists. You might want to rethink about your class design as in your current state calling `TotalCost` more than once will keep increasing the price of the cart. Instead you could add the cost of each item to the cart total at the same time as you append the item to the cart.

You can then user `TotalCost` to return the current cost as it will be increased every time an item is added. You could also add a recalculate the cost of your cart for example if an items cost changed (lets say some discount on one item). then you can recalculate the cart total cost.

The below is just a simple demonstration and i have spent no real time on class design its just an example to highlight it is possible to have class instances in a list

```py
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, customerName, CartID, totalOrderAmount=0, currentSize=0):
        self.CART = []
        self.customerName = customerName
        self.CartID = CartID
        self.totalOrderAmount = totalOrderAmount
        self.currentSize = currentSize

    def addItemToCart(self, item: 'item'):
        self.CART.append(item)
        self.totalOrderAmount += item.getCostOfItem()

    def TotalCost(self):
        return self.totalOrderAmount

    def recalculate_total(self):
        self.totalOrderAmount = 0
        for i in self.CART:
            self.totalOrderAmount += i.getCostOfItem()


class item:
    def __init__(self, name, quantity, cost, ItemType):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.cost = cost
        self.ItemType = ItemType

    def getCostOfItem(self):
        return self.cost * self.quantity


cart = Cart('Chris', 132)
cart.addItemToCart(item('book', 1, 10, 'misc'))
cart.addItemToCart(item('toy', 1, 5, 'misc'))
cart.addItemToCart(item('car', 2, 100, 'misc'))
print(cart.TotalCost())
car = cart.CART[2]
car.cost = int(car.cost / 100 * 90 ) # reduce the cost of the car by 10% discount
cart.recalculate_total()
print(cart.TotalCost())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
215
195
```